# What is a good US Wood to repair some Jarrah furniture?

Tags: wood-selection, hardwood, outdoor

We have a table and set of benches in the garden, made of Jarrah wood. The only treatment they've had is regular coating with Jarrah oil, so they are nice and dark.

Some of the benches have recently been broken by people who shall remain nameless. I can't find a decent Jarrah supply on the California coast. So I guess we'll need to use something native.

Does anyone have a suggestion for something which will darken with age (to match the existing Jarrah) as it is left outside 24/7, and stand up to the wear and tear?

Here's some images of the damaged parts

[image: Ends split where hardware was inserted]
[image: Full piece (you can see an intact one on right]

Comment: Have to lead with this, so there's a "Jarrah Oil" as well as a "Teak Oil"? \* le sigh*

Comment: Sorry for your trouble. There just isn't a domestic US species that's a good match for jarrah. You can get good outdoor durability from white oak, even without treatment,  and like most woods it will darken with treatment with any oil-based penetrating finish (which is what I'm guessing "jarrah oil" is ....same as "teak oil"). I presume you're at least somewhat familiar with white oak, and realise it'll never look the same or likely even come close to the same colouring. A red oak *might* be closer in colouring (it varies too much to rely on as to colour) but that's not exterior durable.

Comment: But a lot of repairs to furniture that has been broken is effected without new wood. It's normal for the breaks to be fixed, even if pieces have become detached. Is there no possibility of that sort of thing in this case?

Comment: Don't know exactly what sizes you're looking for, but have you considered ipe? (Not native, of course, but widely available at decking stores.)

Comment: ps, also Bay Area and working on an ipe deck right now, so maybe some scraps available if we can figure out what you're looking for and manage to get in touch...

Comment: Sorry for the delay .. hadn't been on a SE site for a while. Will check with my son what size pieces he needs. I do have some of the broken parts around but they were splintered badly. No strength left, if I were to reuse them for chair backs

Comment: @Graphus Re: Jarrah Oil, here's Cabot's description "Containing a precise blend of superb-grade linseed oil for maximum penetration, long-oil alkyds for durability and pure South American tung oil for color depth and water repellency, Australian Timber Oil delivers three-way oil protection and a beautiful hardwood stain. In addition, complex translucent iron oxide pigments are added to ensure a lasting U.V.-absorbing surface rich with color and dimension."

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Looks like I need 3 pieces, 4/4 x 3" x 3 1/2 '. It the cross beams for a slatted chair back. They've split at the ends where the hardware was inserted. They are curved, but not "bent" - cut out of a straight piece.

Comment: Added photos -we need to "remake" three of the long pieces.

Comment: Re. the broken-off pieces, in case you don't know a glued repair (if done right) results in joins that are literally stronger than the wood was originally. FWIW from the penetration of the finish/stain in one area (1st photo, jagged edge near the bottom) it looks like there was an existing crack, which the damage partially propagated from.

Comment: Now about Cabot's blurb, as a product description you can take it as a given that it's pure marketing speak since there's zero regulation in this area. And OMG, there's so much wrong here! There's no such thing as "super-grade" linseed oil. If they *really* wanted durability they wouldn't have used alkyd, they'd have used phenolic. Tung oil for colour when linseed oil is nearly always darker? And anyway this is irrelevant as A, colour imparted to wood between light oils and orangey/amber oils is actually surprisingly similar, and B, this is pigmented, so final colour is 99% dictated by that...

Comment: I'm reluctant to name suppliers here because I'll have good and bad things to say about them, but reach out via github and we can talk.

Comment: Might have scraps for you, but won't know for a week or two.

Comment: @Graphus Yep, I know about the gluing but someone didn't tell me it was broken and I have no idea where the pieces are :( And thanks for the info on the oil .. I guessed it was puffery but the table set has sat out in the Californian weather for nearly 20 years with just an annual coating, so I guess it works :) The damage comes from abuse rather than weather.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Didn't realise github had a messaging feature :) I use it all the time, but purely from the command line.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Nope, github has no PM facility and I don't do much social media stuff. If you have my name from Github, I'm pretty easy to find on linkedin, which will give you a messaging approach.

Comment: Surprised about github, but whatchagonnado... you'll see me on linkedin.

Comment: *"I guessed it was puffery but the table set has sat out in the Californian weather for nearly 20 years with just an annual coating, so I guess it works"* Yeah it's fine, but given this is jarrah if you'd done nothing at all to it it would have held up pretty well! Now it wouldn't look the same (obvs!) and to be fair the coloured coating does look good. .....Just a titbit to file away in the back of your mind: what Cabot made here is in essence a semitransparent enamel paint by another name.